# Failure to install package using Anaconda

Tags: python, conda, pythonocc

I want to install PythonOCC.
From the official documentation (http://www.pythonocc.org/download/), i saw that i have to use:

```
conda install -c conda-forge -c dlr-sc -c pythonocc -c oce pythonocc-core==0.18.1
```

So from the base terminal, i typed that command, but i had some conflicts that i am unable to interpet them or find a solution, since this is my first time using Anaconda.
I am on Ubuntu Linux 20.04.

This is the error message:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: / 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                          

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - pythonocc-core==0.18.1 -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']

Your python: python=3.8

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your CUDA driver:

  - feature:/linux-64::__cuda==10.2=0
  - feature:|@/linux-64::__cuda==10.2=0

Your installed CUDA driver is: 10.2
```

Any ideas on how to proceed from here?

**EDIT:** After following user's vc 74 suggesttions, i tried these commands:

```
conda create -n py36 python=3.6
conda activate py36
conda install -c conda-forge -c dlr-sc -c pythonocc -c oce pythonocc-core==0.18.1
```

This is the new conflict i got:

```
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                          

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versionsThe following specifications were found to be incompatible with your CUDA driver:

  - feature:/linux-64::__cuda==10.2=0

Your installed CUDA driver is: 10.2
```

Comment: The issue is quite explicit, pythonocc-core is not available for python 3.8. If 3.8 is not mandatory, you can switch to python 3.6 (`conda create -n py36 python=3.6)`

Comment: So i run the command you just supplied and then 'conda install -c conda-forge -c dlr-sc -c pythonocc -c oce pythonocc-core==0.18.1' ?

Comment: `conda create -n py36 python=3.6`
`conda activate py36`
`conda install -c conda-forge -c dlr-sc -c pythonocc -c oce pythonocc-core==0.18.1`
and see how it goes

Comment: Thanks. I only have one conflict now. I edited the question with the latest conflict.

Comment: _So from the base terminal, i typed that command_ Don't do that! Create a new environment for each project/application, don't mess with the base one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Conda UnsatisfiableError on GitHub](https://github.com/KevinMusgrave/pytorch-metric-learning/issues/55#issuecomment-629698723), this is a problem with the meta.yaml of the package itself, and not your fault at all. I would suggest opening a support ticket with the makers of the `PythonOCC` module. Then they will be able to fix the issue.